# create xml from 3 tables in php

Tags: php, sql, xml

I have 3 Tables, 2 Tables from 1 Database and 1 Table from other Database.

**Database "GER":**
Tables:
1. account
    fields:
    - accountid
    - accountname
2. accountbillads
    fields:
    - accountaddressid
    - bill_city
    - bill_street

**Database "STG":**
Table:
1. edata
    fields:
    - deviceid
    - lat
    - long

Field "accountid" and "accountaddressid" have the same data.
Field "accountname" and "deviceid" have the same data.

How i may to create XML file with this structure in PHP ?

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<markers>
<marker accountid="13" accountname="alex" bill_city="london" bill_street="knighton 13" lat="23.456" long="13.456"/>
</markers>
```

any reference will help me. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all your must have access to both databases.
If you haven't done already, take a look at the GRANT syntax in mysql manual.

After setting correct permissions, you execute your normal queries, using db/tablenames.

For example: 
SELECT ger.account.accountid FROM ger.account WHERE ...

Grant syntax: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html

Select syntax: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

After that, you use php to retrieve data as you want them from both databses to create your xml document